# Transparent the background of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I want to transparentize the background of `UICollectionView`.
I set `BackgroundColor` to default or alpha value to 0, but the background color of the `UICollectionView` range only is black.

Is it possible to transparentize the background color?

Thank you for your consideration.

Please check image:

[image: Please check image]

Comment: you want to see layer1 clearly. right?

Comment: Absolutly yeah Thx.

Comment: Try to set collectionview background clear color.

Comment: U can update your UI view color which contains collection view. Or you can achieve this by using clear color in cells of collection view.

Comment: I checked clear color, then I did it !! Thanks!! XD

Comment: Set UICollectionView’s and Cell’s background color to clear. And set background color to the superview of collectionview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```